# min-height on container to allow child div to stretch stops empty sibling divs from expanding

Tags: html, css, height

I had previous set `body {height: 100%}` and `html {height: 100%}` to allow my columns to span the `viewport` length. Once one of the columns enough content to cause a page overflow I realised the columns weren't stretching with the content (content was running out of the column background). Changing to `body, html {min-height: 100%}` solved one issue but has meant that the columns with less in them stopped spanning the viewport and only grew with their content (which I find weird because all 3 columns share a container). `body{height: auto}` has the same issue.

```css
*{
font-family: 'verdana';
box-sizing: border-box;
}
}
html {
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.row{
 height: 100%;
}
.column1 {
 float: left;
    width: 15%;
    padding: 15px;
    height: 100%; 
 background-color: var(--grey); 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
.column2 {
 float: left;
    width: 60%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-top: 0;
 background-color: var(--light);
}
.column3 {
 float: left;
    width: 25%;
 height: 100%;
 padding-left: 25px;
 background-color: var(--dark);
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}





/* irrelevant to question */
:root {
   --dark: #14161C; 
 
 --lighter: #2A2F3A;
 
 --text: #7C8EB2;
 
 --light: #FEFEFA;
 
 --grey: #EFF2F7;
 
 --blue: #4286F4;
}
/* Site Layout  */
header {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--lighter);
  border-bottom: 4px solid var(--dark);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  color: var(--grey);
  text-align: center;
}

div#title-box, nav {
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-top: 0px;
}

div#title-box {
  width: 15%;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

div#title-box > h1, nav > button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;  
  background-color: var(--dark);
  color: var(--grey);
  line-height: 25px;  
  font-size: 1em;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid var(--dark);
  border-top:none;
}

nav > button {
  border: none;
}

nav > button:hover {
  background-color: var(--light);
  color: var(--dark);
  border-top:none;
}
.postbox{
 background-color: var(--dark);
 color: var(--grey);
 /*margin-top: 20px;*/
 margin-left: 25%;
 width: 75%;
 height: 9%;
 float: left;
 clear: both;
 padding-top: 20px;
 padding-left: 15px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 /*border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;*/
}

.posttext{
 resize: none;
 font-size: 12px;
 overflow: disabled;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: var(--blue); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>


<header>
  <div id="title-box">
    <h1>TITLE 0.1    beta</h1>
</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; padding-top:10px;">
  logged in in as user.
  </div>
  <nav>
    <button href="#">Admin</button>
    <button href="#">Button</button>
    <button href="#">Log Out</button>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column1">

  </div>

  <div class="column2">
   <div class="postbox">
  <textarea class="posttext" placeholder="post update"></textarea><nav><button style="border: 2px solid var(--light); border-radius: 5%;">Post >></button></nav>
 </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column3">
<div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div><div>a</div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```